# BigQuery GSheet Upload

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery, bigdata

Connecting a GSheet to BigQuery is easy and a very cool feature, but it is very slow. It's seems like the data which is stored through an ETL process etc. is really stored in BigQuery, while G-Sheets are only "connected". Is there somehow a way to store data more efficient or does others experience the same and knowing a work around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem with Google Sheet is not only slowness - but also potential human involvement into editing process. So somebody just come and edit (by removing column :) ) - and all your queries will stop working.
Idea we implemented:

1. Create federated table T1 on Spreadsheet
2. Periodically dump (depends on need of freshness) data from T1 to real bigquery table T2 with overriding everything.
3. Use T2 everywhere

Result: you got fast queries (no federated object involved) - and if somebody break spreadsheet - it will not go from T1 to T2 - and you will know about issue but in the same time all queries will continue to work without issue with last known good data.

As idea you may initiate load from modify event on spreadsheet - but I will not go this route - too many moving parts would be involved and reliability of Gscripts still not very high

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. With real bigquery table you mean create empty table with Spreadsheet schema like here: [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/images/create-empty-table.png?hl=de) ??  And then dump data into this table? Do you notice better speed performance?

Comment: So the basic questions for me is, how can I create a "real big query table"? Is it possible with the method I posted above in the link or do I need a other approach like streaming data or load it from cloud storage etc??

Comment: After you define your federated table - just do `select * from [federated_table]` in UI - and set destination table name in some dataset (you need to click show options to access this) - and BigQuery will replicate schema and data here